# MySQL subquery pulls multiple results

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, group-concat

I've got repeating records with different `'manufacturer'` fields. I'm trying to `GROUP BY i.stocknumber` but that only removes a record without collecting the other manufacturer result.

Some records have a `NULL` manufacturer field, and I've tried using `GROUP_CONCAT` in the subquery to elide the differing results for "manufacturer".

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT i.id,i.stocknumber,m.manufacturer
FROM inventory i
INNER JOIN makes mk on i.make = mk.id 
INNER JOIN models md on i.model = md.id 
INNER JOIN classes cl on i.class = cl.id 
LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT idm.id, idm.inventory_id, dm.manufacturer AS 'manufacturer' 
            FROM display_manufacturers dm 
            INNER JOIN inventory_display_manufacturers idm ON dm.id = idm.display_manufacturer_id 
           ) m ON i.id = m.inventory_id 
-- GROUP BY i.stocknumber
ORDER BY i.stocknumber
```

The result I get is:

[image]

Any thoughts on grouping the repeated records by concatenating the `manufacturer` field?

(**NOTE:** I already tried `GROUP_CONCAT` on the subquery)

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
id   | stocknumber | manufacturer
----------------------------------
946  | 011A        | NULL
907  | 1001        | Sports Coach, Coachmen
1032 | 1001x       | Sports Coach
```

etc....

Comment: Have you tried `GROUP_CONCAT` in the main query ?

Comment: Why do you want a list of manufacturer's concatenated together? What's the end game here?  If you're after unique stock numbers and the manufacturer, you're query is spot on.  If you're after just a list of unique stock numbers, exclude the manufacturer...  I don't see the real problem yet...

Comment: See edit for DESIRED RESULT.

Comment: I think @Gordon has done what you're after. Just make sure your group by isn't commented out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT i.id, i.stocknumber, group_concat(distinct m.manufacturer) as manufacturers
. . .
GROUP BY i.stocknumber
```

EDIT:

This version explicitly uses your query as a subquery.  It should not put all manufacturers on the same row:

```
select stocknumber, group_concat(distinct manufacturer) as manufacturers
from (SELECT i.id,i.stocknumber,m.manufacturer
      FROM inventory i
      INNER JOIN makes mk on i.make = mk.id 
      INNER JOIN models md on i.model = md.id 
      INNER JOIN classes cl on i.class = cl.id 
      LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT idm.id, idm.inventory_id, dm.manufacturer AS 'manufacturer' 
            FROM display_manufacturers dm 
            INNER JOIN inventory_display_manufacturers idm ON dm.id = idm.display_manufacturer_id 
           ) m ON i.id = m.inventory_id
     ) t
GROUP BY stocknumber ;
```

Comment: If I put `GROUP_CONCAT` in the main query, it pulls all manufacturers and fills the manufacturer field for all records.

Comment: @gtr1971 . . . Isn't that what you want?

Comment: it's grabbing all manufacturers in the table, not just what belongs to the record.

Comment: @gtr1971 . . . Have you added the `group by` clause?  It should only be including manufacturers for a particular `stocknumber` on each row, assuming that the join conditions are correct (which I assume because it produces your output).

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is removing the NULL fields, you just have to add a WHERE condition excluding the NULL fields

```
SELECT i.id,i.stocknumber,m.manufacturer
FROM inventory i
INNER JOIN makes mk on i.make = mk.id 
INNER JOIN models md on i.model = md.id 
INNER JOIN classes cl on i.class = cl.id 
LEFT JOIN ( 
            SELECT idm.id, idm.inventory_id, dm.manufacturer AS 'manufacturer' 
            FROM display_manufacturers dm 
            INNER JOIN inventory_display_manufacturers idm ON dm.id = idm.display_manufacturer_id 
           ) m ON i.id = m.inventory_id 
WHERE m.manufacturer IS NOT NULL
-- GROUP BY i.stocknumber
ORDER BY i.stocknumber
```

Comment: why uuse a where? just change the query to an inner join. left join will return nulls if there's no matching records on the "right". inner joins won't

Comment: I want NULLS, just trying to get only corresponding manufacturers grouped in the field. Nulls are OK.